# What could cause an MPFI engine to balk when the throttle is opened?

Tags: suzuki, stall, throttle

I'm on the Indian sub-continent. The vehicle in question is a Maruti 800 MPFI ; motive power is provided by a Suzuki F8 engine. The vehicle was purchased new, and has been regularly serviced. The current reading on the odometer is just past 61K. There is no RPM counter, or ammeter.

Background:
A flat battery was replaced a few weeks ago - may not be pertinent to the issue. The engine doesn't sound quite as smooth as it used to.

The problem:

1. When the engine is started cold, it balks immediately after the start - almost stalls. This is automagically remedied - possibly by increased fuel flow - as may be inferred by the racing engine sound.
2. In high gear (either 3, or 4) when I occasionally need to toe the accelerator, the engine balks almost to stall - then gradually recovers.

As a layman my guesses lean towards carbon accumulation in the spark-plugs, or similar impediment in the fuel injectors. I could be wrong.

What could cause an MPFI engine to balk when the throttle is opened?

Comment: Did you check for any vacuum leaks in the air intake

Comment: Maybe pull some plugs and give them a reading... which you already alluded to...  (you don't seem the typical layman)

Comment: @method It didn't occur to me - but surely a leak would be continuous rather than sporadic?

Comment: @SteveRacer ;) It's easy to come across as unlaymanlike on the internet

Comment: @Everyone  Wouldn't that be "laymenlike" ??  Just saying. Cuz you don't seem to eschew being not not un-laymenlike.  Anyhow... pull some plugs and report back.  Better than tea leaves and costs nothing.